# No query Unable to fetch row

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm attempting to write a piece of code that would get selected item from QTableView and delete it from database.

```
QModelIndex index = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();

QString value= ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();
qDebug() << "Value : " << value;

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("TestDatabase.db");

if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal("Failed to connect");
}
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("DELETE * FROM movies WHERE Title='"+value+"'");

if(!qry.exec())
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("error::") , qry.lastError().text());

}

db.close();
```

However, I'm getting 'No query Unable to fetch row' error. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with that.

Update : The issue was that I placed '*' after DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suffers form SQL injection since you are using `prepare()` not correctly. This is also the reason why you get the error. To use `prepare()` the right way it must be followed by at least one `bindValue()`. In your case something like:

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("DELETE * FROM movies WHERE Title = :title");
qry.bindValue(":title", value);
if(!qry.exec()) //...
```

`bindValue()` takes care that `value` is escaped properly and doesn't do any harm.

...if you think that SQL injections aren't a problem, have a chat with [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) :)